# Reveal a button by dragging list item to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to make a list with bootstrap, and for each item I'd like to reveal a button behind the list item while dragging them to the left in order (like in smartphone apps).

Like this : [image: drag to right reveal the blue div]

So I did this JavaScript with jQuery ui

```
$(function() {
        $( "#historique1" ).draggable({
            axis: 'x',
            containment: [-110, 0, 0, 0],
            revert: function() {
            //determine the start/end positions
            var end = $(this).position().right;
            var start = $(this).data('start');
            //subtract end and start to get the (absolute) distance
            var distance = Math.abs(end - start);
            var width = $(this).width();
            //if the distance is more than 80% of the width don't revert
            if(distance > (width * .8))
            {
                return false;
            }
            //else revert
            return true;
            },
            start: function(){
                //get the start position
                var start = $(this).position().right;
                //store the start position on this element
                $(this).data('start', start);
            }
        });
    });
```

When I drag to left but less than 0.8*width the revert is true and my div comes back to the origin position.

But don't know how to move the div to the max-left position if the distance I dragged it is higher than 0.8*width..

I'd like to drag a div (one list item) to the left. If the distance dragged is less than the half, the div comes back to the origin. If the distance is more than the half, the div move to the left and stop to a position

Any other way to do this ? (like a draggable sidebar)

Comment: Can you rephrase your question by explaining what sort of user interaction you are trying to achieve from a users perspective? I didn't get what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Ok sorry ^^
Well i want to drag a div (one list item) to the left.
If the distance dragged is less than the half, the div comes back to the origin.
If the distance is more than the half, the div move to the left and stop to a position.